# Как в Input в val добавить html code?

Tags: html, jquery

Когда я в input value прописываю `html-code (&#8734)`, то строка становится пустой. Как правильно в `input` прописать `html-code`?

```js
$('#element').val('&#8734');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="element" type="number" value="" />
```

Comment: Выложи пример свой сюда в снипет...

Comment: XSS-атака ? Не, не слышал

Comment: @Air
Вот пример:
$('#element').val('&#8734')

Comment: @ryzen, мне в сайт надо в инпут вставить

Comment: @chilo5432, сниппет сделай, а не строчку в комменте напиши. Тем более,эта строчка никак не может оставить инпут пустым.

Comment: @Air, твой сниппет работает не так как описано.

Comment: @Qwertiy, вижу, но увы, телепатических способностей у меня  нет... Поди угадай, что и как там у автора...

Comment: @Air, я в одном из ответов предположил, что у него type=number. Но зачем вообще добавлять в вопрос сниппет вместо автора, если он работает не так, как описано в вопросе?

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно все закодированные символы превратить в обычную строку, и потом записать в значение поля:

```js
let strWithCodes = '&#8734 &#8734!!!&#8734XXX&#8734';
let str = strWithCodes.replace(/(&#\d+)/g, (matchedSubstr, matchedPart) => {
  return String.fromCharCode(matchedPart.substr(2));
});
let input = document.body.querySelector('.my-input');
input.value = str;
```

```html
<input type="text" class="my-input">
```

Если применить не простую замену в строке, а парсинг символов в HTML, то становятся возможны атаки. То есть запись символов в инпут должна идти без этапа обёртки в jQuery и без innerHTML и подобных методов.

Answer (score 2):

Извращение, но работает, если `;` не забывать:

```js
$('input').val($($.parseHTML('&#8734;')).text())
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Внимание: этот код опасен:

```js
$('input').val($($.parseHTML('<img src="ee" onerror="console.log(1)">')).text())
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

А лучше не выпендриваться и писать прям символом:

```js
$('input').val('∞')
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input>
```

Comment: Если применить не простую замену в строке, а парсинг символов в HTML, то становятся возможны атаки. То есть запись символов в инпут должна идти без этапа обёртки в jQuery и без innerHTML и подобных методов.

Comment: Хм.. Но `$.parseHTML` применять безопасно же? Только вот без `;` он не парсит мнемонику...

Comment: В документации jQuery написано что не безопасно (типа безопасно но нет из-за непрямой возможности запуска скриптов) - http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/jQuery.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/index.html

Comment: Так, интересно. Т. е. parseHTML вернул нечто - это уже dom-объекты. Оборачивая dom-объекты в jQuery я ничего у них не вызываю,это тоже можно. но само создание dom-объектов может вызывать обработчики. Гадость какая-то... А исправить как-то можно?

Comment: Я не в курсе. И там кроме обработчиков можно например картинку пропихнуть и следить за юзером как на почтах всяких делают.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, похоже, нативный вариант этим не страдает: `new DOMParser().parseFromString('<img src="ee" onerror="console.log(1)">', 'text/html')`

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, и вот так безопасно (при условии поддержки тега template): `t = document.createElement("template");
t.innerHTML = '<img src="ee" onerror="console.log(1)">';
t.textContent`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106967/discussion-between-pavel-grishaev-and-qwertiy).

Answer (score 1):

В input с типом number нельзя писать всякий мусор. Но можно использовать placeholder и стилизовать его под значение, дополнительно повесив класс, ккоторому эти стили приписаны:

```css
.inf::placeholder {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="&#8734;" class="inf">
```

Comment: Дичь, но гениально! :)

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, ну просто бесконечность и код в комменте точно пишет не пустую строку - должна оставаться та, которая передана. Вот я внезапно и подумал - а вдруг там тип `number`, а не `text`?))) Кажется, сегодня день телепатии xD